# Uploaded Image file name encoding/charset in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a pretty weird problem that I have not faced before, and with a 2-hour search I had no results;

I recently migrated a wordpress site, what I did was;

- Export database and import on new server (via phpMyAdmin)
- Copy Wordpress client files to new database.
- Edit `wp-config.php` relative to new database information.

Everything was working correctly, but only problem was, in new server some of images that is used in posts or as thumbnails are not showing in browser (probably due to Turkish unsafe chars).

As an example, if I inspect the link of the image, wordpress redirects me to 404 page;

**File name:** `çiğ-beslenme-mi-yoksa-pişirmek-mi.jpg`

How wordpress prints it:

`wp-content/uploads/2017/01/%C3%A7i%C4%9F-beslenme-mi-yoksa-pi%C5%9Firmek-mi.jpg`

How I can access it via browser:

`wp-content/uploads/2017/01/c%CC%A7ig%CC%86-beslenme-mi-yoksa-pis%CC%A7irmek-mi.jpg`

For example, for the char `ç` wordpress prints; `%C3%A7` and it is accessible  with `c%CC%A7`

As you can see, I can add a `c` letter before printing `ç` and change %CC%A7 with %C3%A7 or `s` before `ş`, this way, images gets shown again. But I would like to know what is the problem here, or what is the cause of this.

I would love that if there is anyone out there, have a better understanding on charsets illuminate me. I'm positive this would occur with German or Dannish also, since these languages has unsafe latin letters too.

**Additional information;**

- Its a LAMP, no control panel software.
- PHP Version 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
- Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev
- PHP charset:     UTF-8
- Charset in mysql tables (?) utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

If needed I can add more information in demand.

Comment: It would appear that your uploaded file is named incorrectly in the server's filesystem.

Comment: @eggyal it is one thing, but I have been using the filezilla for the whole uploading process, also both new and old server is from same datacenter, I really don't imagine how filenames changes.

Comment: Apache's [`AddDefaultCharset`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset) directive probably doesn't match the encoding used to name the file.